# SQL Join with distinct values from both tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of orders placed by customers and a table of phones of different configurations. I want to find a single record from phones matching each order according to their configuration.

For example, if the order asks for a red phone with 256 GB memory, a phone with a similar configuration should be selected, but that phone should not be selected for the next order if it also asks for a red phone with 256 GB memory.

Please help me with a SQl query that builds the above JOIN.

Comment: Which are you using, MySQL or SQLite?

Comment: Either way, I think this will be very difficult in a JOIN. It's not a relational operation.

Comment: I don't think there's any way for the `ON` condition to be aware of which rows were selected in previous rows of the result.

Comment: If you're trying to avoid returning more phones than you have in inventory, you need to process the orders sequentially. Each order should reduce the count in inventory, and you should only return results that have at least 1 item in inventory.

Comment: could you be a bit more specific and share table schemas?

Comment: I'm using MySQL

Comment: The schema is something like this: Table Phones with PID, Model, Make, Color, Memory, Camera and Sim slots. Table Orders with OID, Customer Name, Color, Memory and Sim Slots

Answer (score 2):

Without sample data and desired results, it is a bit hard to follow your question.  But I think I understand what you are asking.  This is an assignment problem by configuration between two tables.  You want the rows to correspond with no duplicates.

Assuming each table has a configuration, you can use `row_number()`:

```
select o.*, p.*
from (select o.*,
             row_number() over (partition by configuration order by configuration) as seqnum
      from orders o
     ) o left join
     (select p.*,
             row_number() over (partition by configuration order by configuration) as seqnum
      from phones p
     ) p 
     on p.configuration = o.configuration and p.seqnum = o.seqnum;
```